# How to find out $ k $ in this problem

Tags: factorial

If $ k $ is an non negative integer, such that $ 24^k $ divides $ 13! $, what is $ k $ then?

Explanation needed, as I am new to factorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$24^k=(2^33)^k=2^{3k}3^k$$

\begin{align}
13! &= (13)(12)(11)(10)(9)(8)(7)(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)\\
&=2^2(3)(2)(3^2)(2^3)(2)(3)(2^2)(3)(2)M \\
&= 2^{10}3^5M
\end{align}

where $M$ is not divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Edit:

For $24^k$ to divide $13!$, we need $3k \leq 10$ (inspect power of $2$) and $k \leq 5$ (inspect power of $3$).

Hence $k \leq \frac{10}{3}$ and $k \leq 5$.

Hence $0 \leq k \leq 3$.

Comment: Which means the answer cannot be $ k = 3 $ ?

Comment: If it works for $k =3$, it should also works for $0 \leq k \leq 3$.

Comment: What is the need of $ M $  in your answer?

Comment: And why it shouldn't divide 2 or 3

Comment: $M$ is a factor of $13!$ that is not divisible by $2$ and not divisible by $3$. Because to check whether $24$ divide it, it suffices to inspect the power of $2$ and $3$. Hence computing it explicitly is not of interest.

Comment: Okay, I found this hint helpful, but I am not able to approach to final answer, $ k $. Please add that in your answer, it will be very helpful

Comment: Edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

You need $2^{3k}$ and $3^k$ dividing $13!$. Now
$$13!=1\times2\times3\times4\times5\times6\times7\times8\times9\times10\times11\times12\times13$$
and the highest power of $3$ dividing this is
$$1\times1\times3\times1\times1\times3\times1\times1\times9\times1\times1\times3\times1=3^5.$$
Therefore $k\le 5$. But you also have to take into account powers of $2$.
Over to you!

Comment: "Take into account powers of 2".....Explain that. why not only accept $ k ≤ 5 $

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get direct answer but $13!=(4!=\color{green}{24})\times5\times\color{red}{6}\times7\times(8=2\times \color{red}{4})\times 9\times(10=5\times \color{blue}{2})\times 11\times \color{blue}{12}\times 13$

Then $k=0,1,2,3$

Note: I used $(*=*)$ inside that product to reduce number of steps. This is not recommended in any exam etc.

Comment: Quite helpful..

Comment: There was an option (Up arrow) , I pressed it before you said it :) . Tick arrow will be given when you explain why $ k = 0,1,2,3 $ ok?

Comment: Please explain..

Comment: Do you agree with $k=3$?

Comment: if so then note that $24^2$ divides $24^3$, and $24^3$ divides $13!$, then $24^2$ divides $13!$... then $k=2$ also

Answer (score 1):

The highest power of a prime $p$ in $n!$ is given by $$\sum_{k=1} \Biggl \lfloor  \frac{n}{p^k}\Biggr \rfloor  $$ 
$24^k = (2^3 \times 3)^k = 2^{3k} \times 3^k$

**Highest Power of $2$ in $13!$**
Let the highest power be $x$. 
$x= \lfloor \frac{13}{2} \rfloor  + \lfloor \frac{13}{2^2} \rfloor   + \lfloor \frac{13}{2^3} \rfloor  = 10 $

Similarly 
**Highest power of $3$ in $13!$** =$ 5$

Since $24^k= 2^{3k} \times 3^k$ 
$0 \le k \le \frac{10}{3}$  (Since $2^{3k}$ is present in $24^k$ and maximum power of $2$ is $10$)
and $0 \le k \le 5$ (Since maximum power of $3$ in $13!$ is $5$)
Combining the above two inequalities 
$0 \le k \le 3$ 
So $k=0,1,2,3$

You can read more about the formula used [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml)